# R wide to long reshape with column names

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I have data in this format

```
A1 A2 B1 B2  C1  C2
10  5 11  5  21  10
```

And I want to convert it to:

```
  1  2
A 10 5
B 11 5
C 21 10
```

How can I do it in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `gather` into 'long' format, then `separate` the 'key' column into two by splitting before the numeric part, `spread` it to 'wide' and change the 'key1' column to row names

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(df1) %>%
    separate(key, into = c('key1', 'key2'), sep="(?=\\d)") %>% 
    spread(key2, value) %>% 
    column_to_rownames('key1')
#  1  2
#A 10  5
#B 11  5
#C 21 10
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A1 = 10L, A2 = 5L, B1 = 11L, B2 = 5L, C1 = 21L, 
     C2 = 10L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

Answer (score 2):

The tags to the question are r, reshape and reshape2 so we show solutions using each of those.

**1) xtabs** A base R solution is the following.

```
let <- gsub("\\d", "", names(DF))
num <- gsub("\\D", "", names(DF))
tab <- xtabs(unlist(DF) ~ let + num)
```

giving:

```
> tab
   num
let  1  2
  A 10  5
  B 11  5
  C 21 10
```

or for a data frame:

```
cbind(let = rownames(tab), as.data.frame.matrix(tab))
```

giving:

```
  let  1  2
A   A 10  5
B   B 11  5
C   C 21 10
```

**2) reshape** Another base R solution is the following.  `let` and `num` are from above.

```
varying <- split(names(DF), num)
reshape(DF, dir = "long", varying = varying, v.names = names(varying),
  times = unique(let), timevar = "let")[-4]
```

giving:

```
    let  1  2
1.A   A 10  5
1.B   B 11  5
1.C   C 21 10
```

**3) reshape2** Using `let` and `num` from above:

```
library(reshape2)

dcast(let ~ num, data = data.frame(value = unlist(DF)), value.var = "value")
```

giving:

```
  let  1  2
1   A 10  5
2   B 11  5
3   C 21 10
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "
A1 A2 B1 B2  C1  C2
10  5 11  5  21  10"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
melt(df1, measure.vars = names(df1)) %>%
  .[, c("l", "n") := tstrsplit(variable, "")] %>%
  dcast(l ~ n)

   l  1  2
1: A 10  5
2: B 11  5
3: C 21 10
```